# here + ggplot2 particularly ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been trying to clean up my project workflow, and have been using the here package, but have am perplexed at some of the utility.

I set up an Rstudio project in the folder ~\ProjFolder. Within this folder I added a Plots folder ~\ProjFolder\Plots.

But when I try to use ggsave to save a plot into the Plots folder it instead places it in the ProjFolder.

```
library(here)
library(ggplot2)
xdat = rnorm(10)
ydat = rnorm(10)
df = data.frame(xdat,ydat)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = xdat, y = ydat)) + geom_point()
here("Plots", ggsave("ScatterPlot.jpg"))
```

Any help?  Or am I just using the here package ineffectively?

Answer (score 5):

You should do `ggsave(here("Plots", "ScatterPlot.jpg"))`. `here::here` is just a way to provide the right file path, you put it in as a replacement for the path argument in functions that take one.

Comment: Damn! 11 seconds too slow! :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are composing `here()` and `ggsave()` in the wrong order. You want the first argument to `ggsave()` to be the full path, so

```
ggsave(here("Plots", "ScatterPlot.jpg"))
```

Does what you want.